# JSP EL ${stuff} syntax not working

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have two problems. The first one is that I'm using JSP and that I can't solve. The second one is that I'm getting an odd behavior.

When I put this in the doGet() method of my servlet

```
req.setAttribute("test", "SARASA");
req.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/main.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

And this in "WEB-INF/main.jsp":

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%= request.getAttribute("test") %>
<c:out value="${test}"/>
```

The output is:

```
SARASA ${test}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong... what can be the reason for this?

---

Update: I solved it adding

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

In each JSP where I needed it. Oddly, I didn't needed that in another project using some very similar web.xml and pom.xml files (I'm using maven).

Comment: test is the name for the attribute I was setting (see the servlet), mapped to a string that says "SARASA"

Comment: See also bottom of our JSTL wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your web.xml is probably referencing the Servlet 2.3 spec, in which `isELIgnored` is set to `true` by default.  If you reference the Servlet 2.4 spec instead, `isELIgnored` will be set to `false` by default.

If you want to reference the Servlet 2.4 spec, your web.xml header should look something like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
     version="2.4">
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that there was no reference to anything... I didn't saw it because it was in the doctype!!! (I usually ignore that) 

<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >