# difference between using c:out and fn in a HTML element

Tags: jsp, jstl

This works in my JSP

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="<c:out value="${registration.firstName}"/>" size="32" >
```

The above line displays the actual First Name in the text input

if I try this one

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="${registration.firstName}" size="32" >
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="${fn:escapeXml(registration.firstname)}"/>
```

The input box just display ${registration.firstName} and ${fn:escapeXml(registration.firstname)} respectively, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you placing the second and third code lines in a JSP file or a HTML file ?

Comment: Maybe the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374821/jsp-el-stuff-syntax-not-working      will help.

Comment: Thanks @rickz the answer at the link you provided helped