# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

i am trying to make simple spring mvc application, using jdbctemplate,but when i try to open registration page i got this error- java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attribute 'items' must be an array, a Collection or a Map.

last time i used this thing in another applicaton, it worked fine,but this time it is not working :(

here is my controller code and register.jsp

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public ModelAndView registerEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee) {

    List<String> cityList = new ArrayList<String>();
    cityList.add("kashipur");
    cityList.add("moradabad");
    cityList.add("delhi");
    cityList.add("noida");

    List<String> genderList = new ArrayList<String>();
    genderList.add("male");
    genderList.add("female");

    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    map.put("cityList",cityList);
    map.put("genderList",genderList);

    return new ModelAndView("register","map",map);

}
```

register.jsp is

```
<div>
    <form:form method="post" action="/insert" modelAttribute="employee">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name :</td>
                <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender :</td>
                <td><form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${map.genderList}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>City :</td>
                <td><form:select path="city" items="${map.cityList}" /></td>
            <tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email :</td>
                <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone :</td>
                <td><form:input path="phone" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Save" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="getList">Click Here to See User
                        List</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe your problem is caused by the fact that EL is disabled. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374821/jsp-el-stuff-syntax-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this `List<String> cityList`
to this `ArrayList<String> cityList`

same here

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
```

Also try to access map element like this `map['cityList']`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to qualify with `${map.`

Simply write

```
return new ModelAndView("register", map);
```

and in the JSP:

```
<td><form:radiobuttons path="gender" items="${genderList}" /></td>
```

and

```
<td><form:select path="city" items="${cityList}" /></td>
```